# git pull error when trying to deploy to AWS EC2

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, git-pull, pull

I am trying to commit some new lines of code from my repository to Aws. I have everything synced on Github. Trying to do a pull from my repository to the EC2 instance.

I ssh in to my EC2, no issues here, but when I do `"git pull"` (and enter in my github username and password) i get a prompt saying:

```
"You are not currently on a branch. Please specify which branch you want to merge with. See git-pull(1) for details. git pull <remote> <branch>".
```

**Update:**
I tried a `'git checkout master'` before the `'git pull'` but it messed up by EC2, the site is down with these errors - `'Pull is not possible because you have unmerged files. Please, fix them up in the work tree, and then use 'git add/rm <file>' as appropriate to mark resolution, or use 'git commit -a` '

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try `git checkout -b <your_branch>`, it seems that your local Git isn't working in any branch right now.

Comment: With "-b" you are creating a new branch with the given name, while the solution might be simply checking out to an existing one...